# Android- Data is allocated in spinner but when selected not showing the value in spinner

Tags: android, mysql, spinner, retrofit

**Problem**
I am fetching some product category from mysql using Retrofit. The data is coming and allocated in spinner but when I select an item its not displayed. In the drop down menu the items are allocated and the setOnItemSelected listener is also working. But the selected item not showing up in the spinner.
I have tried almost everything also related stackoverflow questions but not working. Pls help me. Thanks in advance.

**Code**

This is the OrderActivity

```
public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

Spinner sp_category,sp_product;
public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/sizzle/";
private List<Product> books;
List<String> prod_cat = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_prod_cat;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

    //sp_product = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_product);
    getBooks();
    sp_category = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
    sp_category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String category = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),category,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}


private void getBooks(){
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build();

    ProductAPI api = adapter.create(ProductAPI.class);

    api.getProduct(new Callback<List<Product>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Product> list, Response response) {
//Dismissing the loading progressbar
            loading.dismiss();
            books = list;
            for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
                prod_cat.add(books.get(i).getProductCategory());
                System.out.println("added");
            }
            Set<String> citySet = new HashSet<String>(prod_cat);
            prod_cat.clear();
            prod_cat.addAll(citySet);
            prod_cat.add("Select Category");
            showListinSpinner();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void showListinSpinner(){
    //String array to store all the book names
    String[] items = new String[prod_cat.size()];

    //Traversing through the whole list to get all the names
    for(int i=0; i<prod_cat.size(); i++){
        //Storing names to string array
        items[i] = prod_cat.get(i);
    }

    //Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    //setting adapter to spinner
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    sp_category.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Creating an array adapter for list view
}
```

}

**This is the layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res   /android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.skipper.ash.ashtet.OrderActivity">
 <Spinner
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_category"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Let me know if it shows the correct toast when you select item from spinner.??

Comment: yeah its showing the toast. but the value is not set in the spinner

Comment: try the answer below..hope it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create xml file in layout folder named `item_spinner` and write the code below in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#000000" >
```

and change in your code while creating adapter.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
                      R.layout.item_spinner, items);
```

also change the sequence of the statements

```
sp_category.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

First set adapter to spinner and then fire data set changed event.

Hope it'll help you.

**EDIT**

> I observed lot of time that if we set the adapter to `ListView` or `Spinner` programatically using `ArrayAdapter` and uses `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item_1` or any other build in layout, then it sets the text color of item to white. I didn't get it why it sets the white color to text by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. It worked like a charm.
But I did not understand the solution.
Can you pls explain?